# Parallel Array Based Data Structure vs Pointer Based Data Structure

Tags: python-3.x, performance, data-structures

I am wondering if I should make a pointer based version of a binary tree or an parallel array version of a binary tree. The main operations are insert and randomly traverse by a fisher yates shuffle.

I have not gotten to the methods or tests but I have some pseudo code for the member variables.

```
"""
Operations and Fequency:
Insertion (Very Frequent) 
Random Ordering (Each key, value once in a random order)  (Very Frequent) 
Set item with key (Somewhat frequent) 
Get item with key (Somewhat frequent) 

The random ordering has to visit every node and be exactly once 
I know I can make a pointer based data structure which can share nodes (space efficency) 
Also, I know I can make a data structure from parallel arrays (is this more efficent?) 
"""


from typing import Generics 
from typing import TypeVar

K = TypeVar('K') 
V= TypeVar('T') 

#Psudeo Code Ideas:
class PointerBasedTree:
    __key: K 
    __val: V 
    __length: int 
    __is_head: bool #Alllows part of one tree to share nodes with another 
    
    #allows immutable data to be "deleted", insertion function can just early return to enforce deletions 
    __is_removed: bool 
    
    __left_tree: PointerBasedTree = self #self is sententail node 
    __right_tree: PointerBasedTree = self #self is sententail node 
    __ordering: List[PointerBasedTree] #can NOT have senentail nodes since self is a possible order for an entry (do NOT yield None)  
class ArrayBasedTree: 
    __keys: List[K]
    __vals: List[V]
    __is_removed: List[bool] #lazy delete to insert to array element in middle of list  
    __left_keys: List[int] #int is row of left key (left tree val is same row) 
    __right_keys: List[int] #int is row of right key (right tree val is same row)
```